# Mocking function object with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I currently have an object that is used to interact with my API `api.js`:

```
export var Auth = (function () {
    var Login = async function(username, password) {
        //Async login code for interacting with the API
    };
    return {
        Login: Login
    }
});
```

And this object is imported inside another file, `login.js`:

```
import * as API from './api';

export var LoginRequestHandler = function() {
   //processess user input, then calls:
   try {
       await API.Auth().Login(username, password);
   } catch(e) {
       throw new Error(e);
}
```

This is my jest test:

```
import * as API from '../api';
import * as User from '../user';

jest.mock('../api');

const spy = jest.spyOn(API.Auth(), 'Login');
    User.LoginRequestHandler().then(() => {
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('theUsername', 'thePassword');
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This is my mock file, `__mock__/api.js`:

```
export var Auth = (function () {
    var Login = async function(username, password) {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    };
    return {
        Login: Login
    }
});
```

I retrieve `theUsername` and `thePassword` through `document.getElementId()` in the `LoginRequestHandler` and create my own DOM for the test above.

Adding `console.log(username)` in the `LoginRequestHandler` reveals that it is being called and is able to get the right values. Furthermore, adding a `console.log(username)` in `API.Auth().Login` also reveals that it is getting the right values as well. However, when I look at my test logs, I see: `Number of calls: 0` for the mock function and the test results in errors.

I assume that I am trying to spy on the wrong function, and is there anyway that I can fix this?

Comment: It's unclear what's the use for `__mock__/api.js` , it seems unused. It's `__mocks__` and not `__mock__` (see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks ), also `__mocks__` isn't used to mock local modules AFAIK. The problem I see is that Auth is factory function for no obvious reason, `spyOn(API.Auth(), 'Login')` does nothing because a spy can't be accessed again, `API.Auth().Login !== API.Auth().Login`. A simple way to improve testability is to refactor `Auth`.

Comment: @EstusFlask what would be the best way to refactor it? Just putting functions in the main scope of the module?

Comment: If `API.Auth()` object is stateless then It can be `export let auth = { async login() {...} }`. This allows to mock it with `spyOn`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `API.Auth()`, it will return a new object which has a `Login` method. So, the object created in `LoginRequestHandler` function and created by `jest.spyOn(API.Auth(), 'Login')` statement in your test case are different. The spy is only added to the later one. The `Login` method in `LoginRequestHandler` function is not spied.

So, here I am going to use `jest.mock()` to mock the `api.js` module without putting mocked object to `__mocks__` directory. E.g.

`api.js`:

```js
export var Auth = function () {
  var Login = async function (username, password) {};

  return {
    Login: Login,
  };
};
```

`user.js`:

```js
import * as API from './api';

export var LoginRequestHandler = async function () {
  const username = 'theUsername';
  const password = 'thePassword';
  try {
    await API.Auth().Login(username, password);
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
};
```

`user.test.js`:

```js
import * as API from './api';
import * as User from './user';

jest.mock('./api', () => {
  const auth = { Login: jest.fn() };
  return {
    Auth: jest.fn(() => auth),
  };
});

describe('61643983', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it('should login', () => {
    expect.assertions(2);

    return User.LoginRequestHandler().then(() => {
      expect(API.Auth).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(API.Auth().Login).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('theUsername', 'thePassword');
    });
  });

  it('should throw error', () => {
    expect.assertions(4);
    const mError = new Error('user not found');
    API.Auth().Login.mockRejectedValueOnce(mError);

    return User.LoginRequestHandler().catch((e) => {
      expect(API.Auth).toBeCalled();
      expect(API.Auth().Login).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('theUsername', 'thePassword');
      expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(Error);
      expect(e.message).toMatch(/user not found/);
    });
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```js
 PASS  stackoverflow/61643983/user.test.js (11.507s)
  61643983
    ✓ should login (5ms)
    ✓ should throw error (3ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 user.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.023s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61643983